# Compare No of Open Accounts with Closed account by month using T-SQL

Tags: sql

I have one table called caseheader and an other table called lookup Item. I would like to calculate case closure rate by using this formula:

> (Total Cases closed in a Month) / Total Open Cases in a `month * 100`

To Calculate opencases CaseCreationDate is being used to get the cases open in a month regardless it is closed or not.

To Calculate ClosedCase CaseCompletionDate is being used to get the Closed cases in a month.

**Total Cases Closed in a given year**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  YEAR(CasecompletionDate) AS YearCompleted
 ,DATENAME( MONTH , DATEADD( MONTH , MONTH(ch.CaseCompletionDate) , -1 ) ) AS 'Month Name Closed'   
 ,MONTH(CasecompletionDate) AS MonCompleted
 ,COUNT(CaseHeaderId) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(casecompletiondate)) AS ClosedBYMonth
FROM  CaseHeader CH
    JOIN LookupItem LI3
        ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId  
        AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE YEAR(CaseCompletionDate) = 2013 
AND LI3.ItemName IN ('Screening', 'In the form required')
AND ch.isdeleted = 0
ORDER BY MONTH(CasecompletionDate)
```

**Total Open Cases in a given Year**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  YEAR(CaseCreationDate) AS YearOpen
 ,DATENAME( MONTH , DateAdd( MONTH , MONTH(ch.CaseCreationDate) , -1 ) ) AS 'Month Name Opened' 
 ,MONTH(CaseCreationDate) AS MonOpen
 ,COUNT(CaseHeaderId) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(CaseCreationDate)) as NewBYMonth
FROM  CaseHeader CH
    JOIN LookupItem LI3
        ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId  
        AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE year(CaseCreationDate) = 2013 
AND LI3.ItemName not like 'Restor%'
AND ch.isdeleted = 0
ORDER BY MONTH(CaseCreationDate)
```

How should I join this to get the closure rate according to given formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT
    2013 AS intYear,
    MonCompleted AS intMonth,
    DATENAME( MONTH, (MonCompleted AS VARCHAR) + '/01/2013' ) AS MonthName,
    ClosedBYMonth,
    NewBYMonth,
    ClosedBYMonth/NewBYMonth * 100 AS calc
FROM
(
SELECT
    MONTH(CasecompletionDate) AS MonCompleted,
    COUNT(CaseHeaderId) AS ClosedBYMonth

FROM  
    CaseHeader CH
INNER JOIN 
    LookupItem LI3
            ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId        
WHERE   
CaseCompletionDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '12/31/2013'
AND LI3.ItemName IN ('Screening', 'In the form required')
AND ch.isdeleted = 0
AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(CasecompletionDate)
) AS ClosedCases

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
 ,MONTH(CaseCreationDate) AS MonOpen
 ,COUNT(CaseHeaderId) as NewBYMonth
FROM  
    CaseHeader CH
INNER JOIN 
    LookupItem LI3
            ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId          
WHERE 
CaseCreationDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '12/31/2013'
AND LI3.ItemName not like 'Restor%'
AND ch.isdeleted = 0
AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY 
MONTH(CaseCreationDate) 
) AS AS OpenCases
    ON ClosedCases.MonCompleted = OpenCases.MonOpen
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have added few bits because there were some syntax errors. Logic is fine. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @YEAR AS INT
SET @YEAR = 2013
SELECT
    @Year AS intYear,
    MonCompleted AS intMonth,
    MonthNameCompleted AS MonthName,
    ClosedBYMonth,
    NewBYMonth,
    CAST(ClosedBYMonth AS DECIMAL (9,2))/ (NewBYMonth)*100 as ClosureRate

FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MONTH(CasecompletionDate) AS MonCompleted,
        DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(CaseCompletionDate) , -1 ) ) AS 'MonthNameCompleted',
        COUNT(CaseHeaderId) AS ClosedBYMonth

```
FROM  
    CaseHeader CH
INNER JOIN 
    LookupItem LI3
            ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId        
WHERE   
YEAR(CaseCompletionDate) =@YEAR 
AND LI3.ItemName IN ('Screening', 'In the form required')
AND ch.isdeleted = 0
AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP BY MONTH(CasecompletionDate)
) as ClosedCases
```

INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
      MONTH(CaseCreationDate) AS MonOpen
     ,DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(CaseCreationDate) , -1 ) ) AS 'MonthNameOpen'
     ,COUNT(CaseHeaderId) as NewBYMonth
    FROM
        CaseHeader CH
    INNER JOIN 
        LookupItem LI3
                ON LI3.LookupItemId = CH.CaseStageLKId
    WHERE 
    Year(CaseCreationDate) = @YEAR 
    AND LI3.ItemName not like 'Restor%'
    AND ch.isdeleted = 0
    AND LI3.IsDeleted = 0
    GROUP BY MONTH(CaseCreationDate) 
    )  AS OpenCases
    ON ClosedCases.MonCompleted = OpenCases.MonOpen